# How do I send multiple requests asynchronously and return successes using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, completable-future

Let's say I have 5 requests, and I want to send all 5 in parallel. I can do this using CompletableFuture.allOf(); However, allOf() only return if ALL futures are successful, and will fail if even one fails. How can I get x out of n successful futures, and disregard the one's that failed while still sending the requests in parallel?

Steps I'm trying to take:

```
1. Send 5 messages in parallel
2. After 10 second timeout, return all successful messages even if any failed
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception individually and return null for those exception scenarios:

```
private CompletableFuture<GreetHolder> getGreeting(String lang) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
        try {
            log.info("Task execution started.");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            log.info("Task execution stopped.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new GreetHolder(getGreet(lang));
    }, executor).exceptionally( ex -> {
        log.error("Something went wrong : ", ex);
        return null;
    });
}

CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(getGreeting("en"), getGreeting("es"));
```

For more information visit this page: https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0